# Выравнить изображение по центру по вертикали и горизонтали

Tags: html, css

Каким образом выравнить изображение по центру по вертикали и горизонтали **без использования CSS3**? Я сделал с использованием `text-align: center` и `margin-top: 10px;`, но не считаю этот вариант правильным, так как постоянно гадать какой `margin-top` прописать, чтобы изображение встало по центру — не вариант.

Чистый код, без выравнивания:

```css
.icons {
  background: url('http://uxen.ru/images/css-sprite-combined.png?1') no-repeat;
}

.icons.plus {
  display: inline-block;
  background-position: -0px 0px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.button_wrap {
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 30px; 
  height: 30px; 
  background: #65d1e0; 
  font-size: 0; 
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button_wrap .button {
   
}
```

```html
<div class="button_wrap">
  <div class="button">
    <div class="icons plus"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g3mxLLm7/1/

Код с выравниванием, считаю, что не совсем правильно использовать `text-align: center` и `margin-top: 10px;`:

```css
.icons {
  background: url('http://uxen.ru/images/css-sprite-combined.png?1') no-repeat;
}

.icons.plus {
  display: inline-block;
  background-position: -0px 0px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.button_wrap {
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 30px; 
  height: 30px; 
  background: #65d1e0; 
  font-size: 0; 
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button_wrap .button {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button_wrap">
  <div class="button">
    <div class="icons plus"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g3mxLLm7/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут может прийти на помощью старый добрый `display: table;` и `display: table-cell;`

Классу `.button-wrap` задаешь `display: table;`, а самой кнопке т.е классу `.button` задаешь `display: table-cell;`, `text-align: center;` и `vertical-align: middle;`.

Также есть еще есть [хороший и удобный сервис](http://howtocenterincss.com/) который помогает решить проблему с центрированием элементов учитывая старые версии браузера IE.

Используя вышесказанное, применяем и смотрим на результат:

```css
.icons {
  background: url('http://uxen.ru/images/css-sprite-combined.png?1') no-repeat;
}

.icons.plus {
  display: inline-block;
  background-position: -0px 0px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.button_wrap {
  display: table; 
  width: 30px; 
  height: 30px; 
  background: #65d1e0; 
  font-size: 0; 
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button_wrap .button {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="button_wrap">
  <div class="button">
    <div class="icons plus"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```